# Which formula to be used for calculating no of iterations?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I wanted to perform a comparison against 8000 data.

- To be more clear, my 1st data has to be compared with the rest of 7999 data and not within itself (i.e not 1st data against 1st data).
- Similarly if 1st data is compared against 2nd data, I will not be performing the comparison against 2nd data against 1st data again.
- This base applies for all the data.

Now I would like to find the actual comparison count for 8000 data. Which formula can be applied to get the needed result?

Comment: So is it so that the $k$th data will be compared to $k+1$, $k+2$, $\dots  7999, 8000$, for all $k$? If this is the case, you can see that the first is compared to exactly $7999$ data, the second one to $7998$ data, the third one to $7997$ etc... So the total number is $7999 + 7998 + 7997 + \dots + 2 +1 = 1 + 2+ 3 \dots + 7998 + 7999$. Do you know how to calculate this sum?

Comment: Calculate the sum (which is the total number of comparisons) and multiply it by the time it takes to calculate one of them. In this case, the total number of comparisons should be $31~988~001$, and that times $0.01~\text{ms}$ is about $319~\text{ms}$, which is a fraction of a second. But $0.01~\text{ms}$ sounds like a very quick operation...

Comment: Ah yes, I made a typo on the calculator.
$$
31988001\times 0.01 \times 10^{-3}~\text{s} = 319.88~\text{s} = 5.33~\text{min}
$$

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n 1=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(n-i)=\frac 12 n(n-1)$$ which is the half of the number of terms in an $n \times n $ matrix (excluding the diagonal part since you do not compare $k$ against $k$).